# Golang MySQL error - packets.go:33: unexpected EOF

Tags: mysql, go

I am switching my entire code base from PHP to Go and during several processes that run, I randomly get this error:

```
[mysql] 2016/10/11 09:17:16 packets.go:33: unexpected EOF
```

Here is my db package that handles all connections to the database:

```
package db

import (
    "database/sql"
    _ "github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql"
    "pkg/db"
)

var connection *sql.DB
var err error

func GetConnection() *sql.DB {
    if connection != nil {
        fmt.Println("********** CHECKING PING")
        err = connection.Ping()
        if err == nil {
            fmt.Println("************ CONNECTION STILL ACTIVE")
            return connection
        } else {
            fmt.Println("********** PING ERROR: " + err.Error())
        }
    }

    connection, err = sql.Open("mysql", db.DEVUSER + ":" + db.DEVUSER_PASSWORD + "@tcp(localhost:3306)/main?parseTime=true")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    return connection
}
```

Is there anything I'm doing wrong with this db package that causes this error to be thrown? What exactly does this error mean? I make sure to return the current connection if there is one open so for multiple requests it uses the same connection object.

Here's an excerpt from the mysql packets.go:

```
// Read packet to buffer 'data'
func (mc *mysqlConn) readPacket() ([]byte, error) {
    var payload []byte
    for {
        // Read packet header
        data, err := mc.buf.readNext(4)
        if err != nil {
            errLog.Print(err)
            mc.Close()
            return nil, driver.ErrBadConn
        }

        // Packet Length [24 bit]
        pktLen := int(uint32(data[0]) | uint32(data[1])<<8 | uint32(data[2])<<16)

        if pktLen < 1 {
            errLog.Print(ErrMalformPkt)
            mc.Close()
            return nil, driver.ErrBadConn
        }

        // Check Packet Sync [8 bit]
        if data[3] != mc.sequence {
            if data[3] > mc.sequence {
                return nil, ErrPktSyncMul
            }
            return nil, ErrPktSync
        }
        mc.sequence++

        // Read packet body [pktLen bytes]
        data, err = mc.buf.readNext(pktLen)
        if err != nil {
            errLog.Print(err)
            mc.Close()
            return nil, driver.ErrBadConn
        }

        isLastPacket := (pktLen < maxPacketSize)

        // Zero allocations for non-splitting packets
        if isLastPacket && payload == nil {
            return data, nil
        }

        payload = append(payload, data...)

        if isLastPacket {
            return payload, nil
        }
    }
}
```

The first "errLog.Print(err)" is line 33 in the "Read packet header" section.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

I added a few log.Println to the connection package and let the process run, and right where I get this error, this is what the console prints:

```
********** CHECKING PING
************ CONNECTION STILL ACTIVE
[mysql] 2016/10/11 11:57:27 packets.go:33: unexpected EOF
********** CHECKING PING
************ CONNECTION STILL ACTIVE
```

Comment: The error your printing says `packets.go:33: unexpected EOF`, what is line 33 in packets.go?

Comment: The source of the error isn't in the code you've posted, but `GetConnection` never assigns a value to the global `connection` variable. Is it supposed to?

Comment: I didn't even catch that. I've edited.

Comment: so, the error is coming from `mc.buf.readNext`, what is that? It would really help to have a full example here.  Either the connection is closing early, or the data is shorter than you expect for some reason. Since you say it's random, I would guess it's former. The other thing you should do with "random" problems, it to make sure you test with the race detector.

Comment: Is there any hard in this message for the time being? Or, if the connection closes early and makes a db request, does it throw that error and just open back up?

Comment: I have no idea what "mc.buf.readNext" is. That's not my code, it's in the mysql package.

Comment: Check out my edit. Would this work? Checking to see if the connection is still alive with connection.Ping() and if an error is thrown reset the connection?

Comment: Sorry, I assumed the log line you posted was coming from your code. Are you saying that there is no error in your code, and this is just getting logged? Then the original fix to assign the global `connection` may have taken care of your problem, since `sql.Open` should only be called once.  The server is closing connections for some reason, maybe because you have too many open. You should also set a sane limit with `SetMaxOpenConns`

Comment: Yes, that is correct. There is no error in my code. I've added SetMaxOpenConns(10) in addition to my initial edit and it is still giving me the error.

Comment: @JimB look at my latest edit. I added a few Println's and look at my console output right when I get that error. That makes me even more confused because it's saying my connection was active the entire time.

Comment: `sql.Open` returns a `*sql.DB`, which is a connection _pool_, your `connection` variable doesn't correspond to a single TCP connection.

Comment: What update to my code do you recommend?

Comment: You haven't shown any of the code that interacts with the DB, so there's not much we can do without an [mcve].

Comment: The only thing my code is doing is calling connection.QueryRow and passing in a query string. That's it. Sometimes it throws the error and other times it doesn't. The error comes some time in the QueryRow function as I have printed out things before and after before the row is scanned into a struct. It doesn't make any sense. But, that is literally all I'm doing. And if I'm not using the sql.DB correctly you could shed some light on how I could update my code.

Comment: I got the same error:
[mysql] 2017/02/08 16:31:56 packets.go:33: unexpected EOF
[mysql] 2017/02/08 16:31:56 packets.go:130: write tcp 127.0.0.1:49188->127.0.0.1:3306: write: broken pipe

-- this error happened after there is no request sent to server within 10 hours. Not sure whether it's related to https://github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql/issues/257

Comment: Did you try setting the number of idle connections to 0?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like the link to the [github issue](https://github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql/issues/257) provided the fix. The fix, at least for my situation was setting the **MaxIdleConnections** to 0. I have kept a server up for 24 hours, running queries against it every several hours and have yet to reproduce the error.

Thanks to @city for the link.

Comment: I am also getting the same error. but setting `MaxIdleConnections to be 0` didn't work for me. `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47406876/unexpected-eof-and-busy-buffer-in-go-sql-driver-mysql-packets-go`

Comment: The best solution we have is disable pooling? I'm not okay with this. I will update once I find something  better.

Answer (score 1):

```golang
import (
    "database/sql"
    "time"
)
//..snip...
db, err = sql.Open("mysql", url)
db.SetConnMaxLifetime(time.Minute * 4) // <-- this
```

did it for me. Explanation: [here](https://github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql/issues/674#issuecomment-345661869)

Answer (score 1):

```
func parent() {
conn, err := db.ClientCat.Conn(ctx)
if err != nil {
    return nil, customError.MySqlConnectionError(ctx, errors.New("Connection_not_Established"))
}
//execute some query
defer conn.Close() //*******this won't close until child() finishes
child()
```

}

```
func child() {
//under high traffic it won't get connection as they are taken by parent method
//usually we have 10,20,100 etc.. connections available as per configuration, under high traffic all will be taken by parent
conn, err := db.ClientCat.Conn(ctx)
if err != nil {
    return nil, customError.MySqlConnectionError(ctx, errors.New("Connection_not_Established"))
}
//execute some query
defer conn.Close()
```

}

this can also happen in above scenario, please verify.
if system is under load and we have received hundreds of requests then this issue can happen.

basically every time request was going to make connection in child method, it was waiting for connection for a long time then timing out as connections are held by parent method.

also parent method won't be over till child method completes. but child method will wait for connection. So once our parent method has made number of connection = max connection then even in parent method it can start failing to get connection for next requests

Answer (score 0):

DSN adds net_write_timeout option

```
root:root@tcp(localhost:3306)/prod?net_write_timeout=6000
```