# unexpected EOF and busy buffer in (go-sql-driver/mysql) packets.go

Tags: mysql, go

I am getting the `unexpected EOF and busy buffer` error in `go-sql-driver/mysql` despite after setting the `SetConnMaxLifetime`, `SetMaxIdleConns` and `SetMaxOpenConns` as suggested [here](https://github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql/issues/257). Can anyone tell me the proper solution of this issue nothing seems to work for me?

```
db, err := sql.Open("mysql", "USERNAME:PASSWORD@tcp(IP:PORT)/DB?charset=utf8")
checkErr(err)
db.SetConnMaxLifetime(time.Second * 5)
db.SetMaxIdleConns(0)
db.SetMaxOpenConns(151)

rows, err := db.Query("Select col1, col2, col3 from tbl")
checkErr(err)

for rows.Next() {
    var col1 string     
    var col2 int32
    var col3 uint64

    err = rows.Scan(&col1, &col2, &col3)
    checkErr(err)  
    Process(col1, col2, col3)

}
```

Comment: `unexpected EOF` could be due to the connection closing before you can read entire data. Try setting a higher `db.SetConnMaxLifetime`.

Comment: I tried but didn't work

Comment: Are yuo getting the mentioned error occasionally or allways

Comment: Yes, I am getting the same error everytime

Answer (score 2):

I setup a local MySQL database and ran your code:

```
package main

import (
    "database/sql"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "time"

    _ "github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql"
)

func main() {
    db, err := sql.Open("mysql", "root@tcp(localhost)/test?charset=utf8")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }

    db.SetConnMaxLifetime(time.Second * 5)
    db.SetMaxIdleConns(0)
    db.SetMaxOpenConns(151)

    rows, err := db.Query("SELECT col1, col2, col3 FROM tbl2")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }

    for rows.Next() {
        var col1 string
        var col2 int32
        var col3 uint64

        err = rows.Scan(&col1, &col2, &col3)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatalln(err)
        }

        fmt.Println(col1, col2, col3)
    }
}
```

..and it worked just fine for me. My `CREATE TABLE` statement looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `tbl2` (
`col1` varchar(25) DEFAULT NULL,
`col2` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`col3` bigint(20) unsigned DEFAULT NULL 
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

What does your table structure look like?

Comment: I don't get the error immediately rather I let it read 100k rows from the MySQL table and then I get the error.  As far as table structure is concerned   it contains columns with varchar and int

Comment: Can you update your question to include your `Process` function?

Answer (score 2):

I found two ways for work arround the `packets.go:36: unexpected EOF` error, first way was changing driver to `ziutek/mymysql` driver, works ok and more or less with the same performance.

Second way, with the default driver, is to set `db.SetMaxIdleConns(100)` and `db.SetMaxOpenConns(100)`, my mysql has max_connections to 151, 
so I thought that limit to 100 will be ok.

In addition, prepared statements has speeded up a lot, before they were slower than Db.Query, now are at least twice as fast. (Tested with 200k queries in 20 goroutines)

I think the problem could be in file `buffer.go` of driver `go-sql-driver/mysql`, in line: `nn, err := b.nc.Read(b.buf[n:])`, some kind of timeout.

Answer (score 2):

According to [go-sql-driver/mysql/issues/314](https://github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql/issues/314#issuecomment-74198485), `bad_buffer` could also happen when attempting to run multiple statements within a transaction while still having an open `*sql.Rows`.

Ensuring that all `*sql.Rows` were closed before running subsequent statements resolves the issue.

#### Before

```golang
rows, queryErr = tx.Query(selectQuery, queryArgs...)

// process rows.Next()

// Attempt to perform additional query
rows2, query2Err = tx.Query(selectQuery2, query2Args ...)

// Get bad_buffer error (from logs:)
// [mysql] {timestamp} packets.go:447: busy buffer
// [mysql] {timestamp} connection.go:173: bad connection
```

#### After

```golang
rows, queryErr = tx.Query(selectQuery, queryArgs...)

defer func(result *sql.Rows) {  
   _ = result.Close()  
}(rows)

// process rows.Next()

// Attempt to perform additional query
rows2, query2Err = tx.Query(selectQuery2, query2Args ...)

defer func(result *sql.Rows) {  
   _ = result.Close()  
}(rows2)

// No error
```

Comment: Very helpful, and not at all obvious.
Adding `defer rows.Close()` fixed my issue.

Answer (score 0):

None of these worked for me. I have used the Docker container then I tried to log in to it from the local machine with MySQL client.

mysql -h localhost -P 3306 --protocol=tcp

After this go programme worked fine.