# Go MySQL with SSL - unexpected EOF

Tags: mysql, go

I'm using the [Go MySQL driver](https://github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql) as part of a project. Recently, there was a need to enable SSL on the MySQL database I am connecting to. I have two servers that are configured with `TLSv1.1`. On one server, I am able connect successfully, but on the other I am getting `unexpected EOF` from the library.

I tried setting `MaxIdleConnections` to 0 as described in [Golang MySQL error - packets.go:33: unexpected EOF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39980902/golang-mysql-error-packets-go33-unexpected-eof), but no luck. Prior to enabling SSL, connections to the server were working. There are other apps not written in Go that are able to connect successfully using the same credentials.

When my app runs, the ping command fails immediately. The MySQL server logs are saying `bad handshake`. Is there something off with my connection code below, or is there a database setting that could be refusing to connect with `skip-verify`?

```
import (
    "database/sql"
    "io/ioutil"
    "strings"
    "text/template"

    log "github.com/sirupsen/logrus"
    // Import runtime for MySQL
    mysql "github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql"
)

type DatabaseConnection struct {
    Hostname string
    Port     int
    Database string
    Username string
    Password string
}

func CreateSSLConnection(db *DatabaseConnection) (*sql.DB, error) {
    templateString := `{{.Username}}:{{.Password}}@{{.Hostname}}:{{.Port}}/{{.Database}}?tls=skip-verify`

    conn, err := connectToDatabase("mysql", templateString, db)

    // error: "unexpected EOF"
    err = conn.Ping()
    return conn, err
}

func connectToDatabase(databaseType string, connectionTemplateString string, db *DatabaseConnection) (*sql.DB, error) {
    connectionTemplate := template.Must(template.New("connectionString").Parse(connectionTemplateString))
    builder := strings.Builder{}

    err := connectionTemplate.Execute(&builder, db)
    if err != nil {
        log.WithFields(log.Fields{
            "template": connectionTemplateString,
            "error":    err,
        }).Error("Failed to create connection string")
        return nil, err
    }

    return sql.Open(databaseType, builder.String())
}
```

Comment: Update: I found a setting `ssl-cipher=DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA` that seems to be the culprit. I have opened an issue with the package maintainer on [GitHub](https://github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql/issues/935). Further research pointed me to this [go/tls issue](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/9894). Anyone know if Go is still missing support for this encryption?

Comment: Unlikely to ever be implemented in Go because DHE is slow, has compatibility issues over 1024 bits and is getting removed in browsers. Suggest choosing a different cipher (if that's the problem).